# Maya Python can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, maya

I'm a Python beginner. I'm trying to write a Maya script to create and connect a new locator to the nodes that I've selected. I'm getting an error - `TypeError: file <maya console> line 21: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`, on the line where I connectAttr.

Here is what I have so far:

I assign variables from the nodes that I've selected
I create a locator with the name from the joint, group it, parent constrain it so it moves to the correct location, and then I want to connect it to the existing nodes. This is the 3rd script I've ever written, please explain like I'm 5.

```python
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel= cmds.ls(sl=True)

for s in sel:

    jntn=sel[0]
    cntrl=sel[1]
    gradientMult=sel[2]
    trans=sel[3]
    orient=sel[4]

    print sel
 
    loc = cmds.spaceLocator(n=jntn+"_LOC")
    grp = cmds.group(empty=True, n=jntn+"_LOC_offset")
    cmds.parent (loc,grp)
    cmds.parentConstraint(jntn, grp, mo=False)
    cmds.delete(const)
    cmds.connectAttr(loc+".translateX",gradientMult+"input1x",f)
    cmds.connectAttr(cntrl+".translate",orient+".input1",f)
    cmds.pointConstraint(cntrl,loc, mo=False)
```

Comment: The `spaceLocator` command returns a list,  so if you want to do `loc+".translateX"`,  then you would need to get the locator name inside that list like:  `loc = cmds.spaceLocator(n=jntn+"_LOC")[0]`.  Now you should be able to concatenate the two strings like you have already written.